# Автозавершение любого слова

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Можно сделать так, что бы в `TextBox` с `autocomplete` автодополнялось не только первое введённое слово, а так же все последующие?

**UPD**

Хорошо, спрошу иначе. Из-за чего `autocomplete` работает только на первое слово?

```
this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(new string[] {
            "123",
            "1234",
            "12345",
            "234"});
            this.textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(567, 228);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 22);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 16;
```

Comment: Можно. Приступайте.

Comment: И в чём проблема?

Comment: [Autocomplete Menu](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365974/Autocomplete-).

Comment: Autocomplete работает только на первом слове, потому что он так изначально сделан. Поискав в [сорцах](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBox.cs,813), можно узреть, что из дотнет-кода идёт обращение к неуправляемому коду WinAPI.